# JSON deserialization

Tags: java, json, deserialization

In JSON, when the client sends a numeric data type(with decimlas), what deserialization class should I use on server side. Double?

**Edit:** SS side is java

Comment: Please include what server side technology you are using. ASP.NET, PHP, Ruby, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What server-side language are you using? Java?  If so, what's being stored in the field? Money?  If you need to store precise values, I wouldn't use Double... instead look at [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).